# DialogFragment doesn't stop main thread execution

Tags: android

I'm trying to block code after DialogFragment as the codecan show but it doen't work to be more precise the problem  is that when i call notifiAll the done does't stop to wait and i can't understand why.. can anyone tell my  mystakes. Thanks to all excuse me for my english.

here there is the code:

```
 ModifyDialog modifyDialog=(ModifyDialog)ModifyDialog.CreateNewInstace();
            Thread done=null;

            modifyDialog.SetListener(new ModifyDialog.NoticeDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDialogPositiveButton(DialogInterface dialogFragment) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDialogNegativeButton(DialogInterface dialogFragment) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            });
            modifyDialog.show(
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"selectmode"
            );
            final Button MODIFICA=(Button)v;
            done=new Thread(){
                public void start(){
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            super.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.i("Thread state ","notificated");

                        if (MODIFICA.getText().equals("MODIFICA")) {
                            MODIFICA.setText("Salva");
                            MOD = true;
                            setModificatedElement();

                        } else {
                            MODIFICA.setText("MODIFICA");
                            MOD = false;
                            SaveChanges();
                            setModificatedElement();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `notifyAll()` and `wait()` on different Objects (the inner class's instances, `this` always refers to the instance of the innermost class). Solutions: 
(1) Use `modifyDialog` (has to be final then): `modifyDialog.wait()`, `modifyDialog.notifyAll()` 
(2) Use DialogFragment's (or whatever the outer class you are working on is called) instance: `DialogFragment.this.wait()`, `DialogFragment.this.notifyAll()` 
(3) Declare and set a new `private final Object sync = new Object()` and use `sync.wait()` and `sync.notifyAll()`